# Changing Background color without reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showInfo();" class="nostyle" ></a>
```

I don't have `id` or `class` name because I generated it dynamically in **xslt**.

When I click on it, it shows a previously hidden div that contains an `<a id='close'>` tag. The idea is to change the background color of the first anchor when I click on the close button, but I don't know how I can set that up.

How can I get the anchor which was clicked and therefore change it?

Comment: Your code contains several syntax errors, caused by misplaced quotes. What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out this solution for a page that has multiple hidden divs, and each div has a show/hide link**

http://jsfiddle.net/qfQhq/

**This works for 1 div and 1 hide and 1 show link**

An easy way to do this, is when you click the link to show the hidden div, save a reference to the link by stashing the $(this) pointer into a global variable and then displaying the hidden div. If the link which opens the hidden div has a background-color (or class to do so) you may want to remove it at this point. (if the color only shows up when you close the div, you may want it to disappear when you open the div too?)
Once you click the close button, you can simply reference the same global variable as if it is a DOM element, and change it's background color (or add a class to it, that does it for you).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

1) Create Global Variable

```
var showInfoLink = "null";
```

2) Store $(this) (DOM Element that triggered `showInfo();`)

```
function showInfo() {
    showInfoLink = $(this);
    showInfoLink.removeClass("highlighted"); //if you closed the div & opened again
    $("#hidden_div_selector").css("display", "block"); //show hidden div
}
```

3) Change background-color or the link

```
$("#hidden_div_close_button_selector").click(function(){
    if (showInfoLink != "null")
    {
        showInfoLink.addClass("highlighted"); //color the background of the link
        $(this).css("display", "none"); //hide the hidden div
        showInfoLink = "null";
    }
}
```

4) CSS For 'highlighted' class (changed bg color)

```
.highlighted {
    background-color: #de9f3c; //random color
}
```

make sure this is all in $(document).ready()

```
});
```

Comment: I'm having other issue using your code, it works fine, but for example in the same hidden div i have 2 buttons, one assign the style to the anchor, and the other one cancels the action, if i click first on the cancel button, then go to other option and click to apply the style 2 anchors was clicked before... theres a way to fix thad?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is.. but if you click the hide/cancel button first, and then you click the open/style button there's a problem?

I edited my code, hope it works. I made it so that when you hit cancel it checks to see if the other button was clicked first

Comment: I changed the Global Variable `var showInfoLink = "null"` and I also changed `3) Change background color for link`

Comment: Ohhh you have multiple buttons that are using this function, I thought it was just 2.... hmmmm. That makes things much different. I'm going to write up an example of how to do this. I'm off to lunch right now though

Comment: Hey, I posted an example that works with multiple hidden divs and multiple buttons.

Comment: I saw it, but not works, i post here http://jsfiddle.net/awnTM/22/ an example what i have trying to merge with your code, but not works it all..

Comment: and here a "modification" of your code showing in theory how should works, the main issue is how i'm creating the anchors dinamically in xlst i cant  assign an ID for each one, for instance all the buttons are the same, same code, class, and parameters...

Comment: Hmmm, ok lets start over haha http://jsfiddle.net/awnTM/26/ What else do you wanted it to do?

Comment: ok, thank you, when you click on confirm change the style, when you click on cancel the style will be like the original state, the problem is if i click in buton 1 confirm, button 2 cancel and button 3 confirm the button 2 get the "confirm style"

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference of the first anchor to the showInfo function.
Like onclick="showInfo(this);".
You can set the background color when close button is clicked since you have a reference to the first anchor. Make sense?

Comment: Not it all, how i pass the reference for the close button when is close?